# Filtrar varios id de un json

Tags: javascript, json

tengo un json

```
0: {productId: "3453", productName: "", brand: "", linkText: "", productReference: "", …}
1: {productId: "3451", productName: "", brand: "", linkText: "", productReference: "", …}
2: {productId: "2345", productName: "", brand: "", linkText: "", productReference: "", …}
3: {productId: "3453", productName: "", brand: "", linkText: "", productReference: "", …}
4: {productId: "2345", productName: "", brand: "", linkText: "", productReference: "", …}
```

quiero filtrar varios id, por ejemplo estos dos id "3453" "3451" y tengo esta función que es esta

```
var filteredProducts = getFilteredByKey(data, "productId", "3453");
        console.log(filteredProducts);

function getFilteredByKey(array, key, value) {
  return array.filter(function(e) {
    return e[key] == value;
  });
}
```

funciona pero solo me filtra un id, pero al agregarle otro id ya no me trae nada por consola.

Aclaro la función no es mía, pero pues no la entiendo muy bien, por eso pido ayuda

Comment: Por lo que muestras tu JSON es en un array, por tanto debes leerlo dentro de un bucle para ir revisando cada objeto dentro y verificando el valor del `id`.

Comment: ose primero debo pasar eso a objetos?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes usar un filtro múltiple como este ([ver código fuente aquí](https://gist.github.com/diegochavez/e9019fedefa0553ce7efc12857739322)):

```
function multiFilter(array, filters) {
  let filterKeys = Object.keys(filters);
  return array.filter((item) => filterKeys.every((key) => (filters[key].indexOf(item[key]) !== -1)));
}
```

La ventaja es que puedes declarar un filtro múltiple, basado no solamente en un array de valores para una clave, sino también en diferentes claves del JSON.

Por ejemplo para el caso de esta pregunta sólo tienes que declarar tu filtro así:

```
let filters = 
  {
    productId: ["3453", "3451"]
  };
```

Y luego se lo pasas a la función.

Veamos:

```js
var s = `[
{"productId": "3453", "productName": "P1"},
{"productId": "3451", "productName": "P2"},
{"productId": "3453", "productName": "P3"},
{"productId": "2345", "productName": "P4"},
{"productId": "3451", "productName": "P5"}]`;

var mJson = JSON.parse(s);

let filters = {
  productId: ["3453", "3451"]
};

function multiFilter(array, filters) {
  let filterKeys = Object.keys(filters);
  return array.filter((item) => filterKeys.every((key) => (filters[key].indexOf(item[key]) !== -1)));
}
console.log(multiFilter(mJson, filters));
```

---

Supongamos que quieres refinar el filtro, y traer sólo los productos con `productId` igual a `3453` o igual a `3451` pero cuyo `productName` sea igual a `P3`:

```js
var s = `[
{"productId": "3453", "productName": "P1"},
{"productId": "3451", "productName": "P2"},
{"productId": "3453", "productName": "P3"},
{"productId": "2345", "productName": "P4"},
{"productId": "3451", "productName": "P3"}]`;

var mJson = JSON.parse(s);

let filters = {
  productId: ["3453", "3451"],
  productName: ["P3"]
};

function multiFilter(array, filters) {
  let filterKeys = Object.keys(filters);
  return array.filter((item) => filterKeys.every((key) => (filters[key].indexOf(item[key]) !== -1)));
}
console.log(multiFilter(mJson, filters));
```

Comment: Multifilter siempre reorganiza el array segun el filtro, id en este caso, como se evita ?

Comment: @raulzarza puedes cambiar esto: `let filters = {
  productId: ["3453", "3451"],
  productName: ["P3"]
};` para indicar cómo quieres el filtro. Si lo quieres por `productName` dejas sólo esa clave. O, si lo quieres primero por `productName` y luego por `productId` pasas los parámetros invertidos.